# Opencv2 include problems

Tags: ros, opencv, opencv2, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using fuerte an Ubuntu 12.04 and have an
`include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>` which can't be resolved (`fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory` ).
Iin the manifest I have `<depend package="opencv2"/>` and the file is at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv2/core.
Running rospack export --lang=cpp --attrib=cflags opencv2 shows following output

```
[rospack] Warning: ignoring duplicate cpp tag in export block
-I/opt/ros/fuerte/include/opencv -I/opt/ros/fuerte/include
```

Any idea why it doesn't finde the file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56189/opencv2-include-problems/) by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it working with this:

```
 if(NOT OpenCV_DIR)
 find_path(OpenCV_DIR "OpenCVConfig.cmake" DOC "Root directory of OpenCV" HINTS    "/opt/ros/fuerte/share/OpenCV/")
endif(NOT OpenCV_DIR)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

---

Originally posted by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) with karma: 145 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0